# How to create a column in pandas dataframe using conditions defined in dict

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
input = {'name': ['Andy', 'Alex', 'Amy', "Olivia" ],
        'rating': ['A', 'A', 'B', "B" ],
        'score': [100, 60, 70, 95]}
df = pd.DataFrame(input)
df['valid1']=np.where((df['score']==100) & (df['rating']=='A'),'true','false')
```

The code above works fine to set a new column 'valid1' data as 'true' for score is 100 and 'rating' is A.

If the condition comes from a dict variable as

```
c = {'score':'100', 'rating':'A'}
```

How can I use the condition defined in c to get the same result 'valid' column value? I tried the following code

```
for key,value in c.iteritems():
    df['valid2']=np.where((df[key]==value),'true','false')
```

got an error:

```
TypeError: Invalid type comparison
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define `c` as a `pd.Series` so that when you compare it to a dataframe, it automatically compares agains each row while matching columns with series indices.  Note that I made sure `100` was an integer and not a string.

```
c = pd.Series({'score':100, 'rating':'A'})
i = df.columns.intersection(c.index)
df.assign(valid1=df[i].eq(c).all(1))

     name rating  score  valid1
0    Andy      A    100    True
1    Alex      A     60   False
2     Amy      B     70   False
3  Olivia      B     95   False
```

You can use the same `series` and still use `numpy` to speed things up

```
c = pd.Series({'score':100, 'rating':'A'})
i = df.columns.intersection(c.index)
v = np.column_stack(df[c].values for c in i)
df.assign(valid1=(v == c.loc[i].values).all(1))

     name rating  score  valid1
0    Andy      A    100    True
1    Alex      A     60   False
2     Amy      B     70   False
3  Olivia      B     95   False
```

Comment: Thanks piRSquared. My real dataframe has many columns, and I have many conditions defined from different column names.  The line df.assign(valid1=df[['score', 'rating']].eq(c).all(1))  has hard-coded 'score', 'rating'.   How can I use the key value defined in the condition C as a variable, instead of hard-coded the 'score','rating' in the code ?

Comment: @mnnmountain yeah, good point.  I've updated my answer to generalize.